# MSVC++ 6.0 devshl.dll ERROR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, crash

My school's maintenance crew installed new Acer Veriton computers over the summer and installed MSVC++ 6.0 because they are cheap and lazy. My computer programming class is now suffering having to use a BOOK to learn to code on a COMPUTER.

I looked up the error on various sources and could not find and solution.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MSDEV.EXE
  Application Version:  6.0.8168.0
  Application Timestamp:    35889584
  Fault Module Name:    devshl.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.8168.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   3588a30a
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0003eaed
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Someone please clear this error up for me or give a definite answer of whether or not the program will ever be compatible with our computers.

It's been 2 weeks into the semester already. None of the maintenance crew have computer backgrounds.

Comment: Just run Express on your own machine.  Or find another school.

Comment: Not sure what the precise problem here is that we need to solve. You dump a random error message out of context. You already know that you've got a 20th century compiler while we're already halfway in the second decade of the next century.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC++ 6.0 is vastly out of date and has a lot of problems.  MSVC++ wasn't at all serious about interpreting the language correctly until version 7.1, so you **should not** be using that old version for learning!  That it's not running on Windows 7 is a sign that it should be consigned to the dustbin.

The current version of Visual Studio has an "Express" version which can be had *for free*.  So rip out the old 6.0 first, reboot, and then install the free Visual Studio Express.  Hopefully this will be enough information for your school’s tech people, managers, and whatnot, to convince them.

At least you're getting a real-world experience of what an I.T. department in an office will be like. :)

Now for more bad news:  your book is out of date, too.  Check out the presentations by Stroustrup at the last two Going Native conferences, available on MS's Channel 9 web sites.

What kind of school, BTW?  High school or college?